# Loading ASP.NET bundled Javascript asyncronosly, then calling a callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events, asp.net-bundling, asynchronous-javascript

I have a page that, on load, sends an AJAX call to an endpoint to get HTML and injects that HTML on the page. That HTML contains `<script>`s generated by ASP.NET BundleConfig's `@Scripts.Render()` method. This allows us to have minified Javascript in QA and production and debug ready Javascript in our local dev environment

My issue is that I need to load external Javascript files on the page and once loaded, run a function from within that file. Normally, the HTML chunk would look like:

```
<script src="/js/file1.js" />
<script src="/js/file2.js" />
<script>
    $(function(){
        // function included in file2.js
        myFunction();
    });
</script>
```

My issue with this is since the page's DOM has been loaded, `myFunction();` in Jquery's ready block runs immediately; all while `file1.js` and `file2.js` are still loading. This obviously runs into an `myFunction is undefined` error.

Is there a way to use ASP.NET's bundles when asyncronously loading HTML that contains Javascript files?

Answer (score 1):

a simple fix would be to use `$(window).load()`

`$(document).ready()` runs in sequence when it appears in the code.

`$(window).load()` will run after everything has loaded so can you try this instead of trying to figure a complex way - as this should work. - just a suggestion.

```
<script src="/js/file1.js" />
<script src="/js/file2.js" />
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        // function included in file2.js
        myFunction();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I like the idea. I'll give it a try.

Comment: jQuery normally saves the day when your mind is overloading with complex overkill ideas! let me know if it helps @FillipPeyton

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I think because the window has already loaded and because the event handler is created after the `window` is loaded, the handler isn't hit.

Comment: can you load your scripts synchronous using a javascript function? would that work for you?

Comment: I don't believe so because I need to use `Scripts.Render()` to apply appropriate minification/obfuscation based on environment.